# use thread inside buttonclick in android

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

I am receiving temperature values from a sensor through BLE and storing it in my db and passing the values as an array through intent to graph activity and diplaying a line graph. I am also posting the values to google app engine. i am doing this all within runOnUiThread() and hence my app crashes when there are too many values.Is it possible to pass values into the graph activity on a new thread? or any other better suggestions?

```
     @Override
      public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        final String property = event.getPropertyName();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            try {                  
               if (property.equals(PROPERTY_IR_TEMPERATURE)) {
                double newIRValue = (Double) event.getNewValue();
              //  float newIRValue_1 = (Float) event.getNewValue();
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ir_temperature);
                String value = decimal.format(newIRValue);
                String formattedText = value + DEGREE_SYM;

               float value_chk = (float)(newIRValue);
               String formattedText_1 = String.valueOf(value_chk); 
               String sensorid = test_1;
               String sensortype = "temperature";
            //  write_data(sensorid,sensortype,value);

            //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ARV sensid:"+sensorid+" senstype:"+sensortype, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                long timemilli =  System.currentTimeMillis();
                //Log.d("TIMMEE", String.valueOf(timemilli));
                String time=String.valueOf(timemilli);
                db = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());

                //db.deleteTempReadings();
                // inserting data to temp table
                Log.i("insert", "Inserting Records...");
                );
              Temperature(sensorid,formattedText_1));
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SENSOR_ID:"+t.getSensorId()+"TEMPERATURE: "+t.getTemperature()+"TIME: "+t.getTimestamp(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // reading data from db
                Log.i("Reading", "Reading Records...");

                List<Temperature> temp = db.getAllTempReadings();

                int arraySize=temp.size();
                double tempArray[]=new double[arraySize];
                int timeArray[]=new int [arraySize];


                //Log.d("ans", String.valueOf(temp.size()));


                for (Temperature t : temp) {

                    String log="SENSOR ID: "+t.getSensorId()+"TEMPERATURE: "+t.getTemperature()+"TIME: "+t.getTimestamp();
                    Log.d("Record"+t, log);
                }
                    // Reading values into the array!

                    for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++){

                        tempArray[i]=Double.parseDouble(temp.get(i).getTemperature());


                }

Button btn=(Button)findViewBy Id(R.id.btnGraph);
btn.setOnCLickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
Intent iIntent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GraphActivity.class);
tIntent.putExtra("tempArray",tempArray);
startActivity(tIntent);
}
});
// rest....posting to server code......
textView.setText(formattedText);
      }
   }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temperature value you get from the sensor upto this you have to do stuff in one thread and after that you have to start **three thread** one for the inserting into the DB, the other one for the displaying the line graph and the last and the third one for the posting the data into the google app engine.

Comment: Can i create the new threads within the runOnUiThread() because I am getting the temperature values inside that.

Comment: No, but what you are doing that you are running whole code in one thread and from that thread you are getting the temperature value so you have to wait till that thread give you the temperature value. So , instead of using this thread you have to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and after that whatever you got in onPostExecute(Result) method then      you have to start your another thread.

Comment: I should create a seperate class for Async Task right? but the temperature value is available in property change method. can u give me a rough idea how to go about my code with an example.?

Comment: I have go through your code and found out that you are first inserting your temperature value in your DB and then you are taking all these values from db to show in your graph and into the Google App Engine. am i right? If yes, then you have to insert first into the db and after inserting into the DB start two thread one for graph and other for Google App Engine. I will show you the usage of AsyncTask.

Comment: after this line **List<Temperature> temp = db.getAllTempReadings();** you are able to start two new threads and AsyncTask if not necessary if you are first inserting data into the DB then using that data for graph and app engine.

Comment: I added a thread for the onClick function through which i sent my temperature values to the graph activity, and it worked. Thank You.

Comment: Please if you get your answer then mark it as completed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused here. The idea is to keep slow processing OUT of your UI thread. I suggest you do the writes to the DB and the App engine first in the 'current' (presumably less critical) thread and then when all is done simply update the graph display in the UI thread.

The only reason you need RunOnUiThread is to make changes to the views on the screen.

Comment: The view is also being changed. The last line textView.setText(formattedText) does the updation.